# C# inherit from Dictionary, iterate over KeyValuePairs

Tags: c#, dictionary, foreach

I have a class that inherits from `Dictionary<string, string>`.  Within an instance method, I want to iterate over all `KeyValuePair<string, string>`'s.  I've tried doing the following:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in base)
```

But this fails with the following error:

> Use of keyword 'base' is not valid in this context

How can I iterate over the `KeyValuePair<string, string>`'s in an instance method in a class that derives from `Dictionary<string, string>`?

**Edit:**  I found I can do the following:

```
var enumerator = base.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    KeyValuePair<string, string> pair = enumerator.Current;
}
```

However, I would still like to know if there's a way to do this via a `foreach` loop.

**Edit:**  thanks for the advice about not inheriting from `Dictionary<string, string>`.  I'm instead implementing `System.Collections.IEnumerable, ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>>, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>, IDictionary<string, string>`.

Comment: Don't derive from Dictionary<TKey,TValue>, it will simply lead to unexpected bugs.  It's much more effective to create a wrapper class.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, deriving from the .NET collection classes is generally ill-advised because they don't offer virtual methods for calls not inherited from `object`. This can result in bugs when passing your derived collection in via a base-class reference somewhere. You are better off implementing the `IDictionary<T,TKey>` interface and aggregating a `Dictionary<,>` inside your implementation - to which you then forward the appropriate calls.

That aside, in your specific case, what you want to do is:

```
foreach( KeyValuePair<string,string> pair in this )  { /* code here */ }
```

The `base` keyword is primarily used to access specific members of your base class. That's not what you're doing here - you are attempting to iterate over the items of a particular instance ... which is simply the `this` reference.

Comment: You should sub most in  "don't offer virtual methods for most calls" with any :).  The only virtual calls they "offer" are teh ones inherrited from object

Comment: @JaredPar: I suppose if you discount members inherited from `object` and a few other intervening classes with some virtual methods - you could indeed say that.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with JaredPar's comment that this isn't a great idea. You probably don't want to publicly expose all of the methods of Dictionary to the outside world, so just make the Dictionary a private member variable and then provide your own interface to it.

With that said, the way to do what you're trying to do is:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in this)
```

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulate `Dictionary<string, string>` as a composed field inside custom `class MyDictionary` and implement a custom [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(VS.80).aspx) and [IEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb(VS.80).aspx) (or variations thereof) for MyDictionary (or make a method that implements handy C# [`yield`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0(VS.80).aspx) keyword to produce the items)...

E.g.

```
class MyDictionary : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>> {
    Dictionary<string, string> _dict;

    IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string,string>> GetEnumerator() {
        return new MyEnum(this); // use your enumerator
        // OR simply forget your own implementation and
        return _dict.GetEnumerator();
    } 

    class MyEnum : IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string,string>> {
        internal MyEnum(MyDictionary dict) {
            //... dict
        }

        // implemented methods (.MoveNext, .Reset, .Current)...
```

**This maintains encapsulation of extraneous methods.** 
And you can still iterate over you instances like so **from inside or outside**:

```
// from outside
MyDictionary mdict = new MyDictionary();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in mdict)
    //...

// from inside, assuming: this == MyDictionary instance)
public void MyDictionaryMethod() {
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in this)
        //...
```