# Is it possible to set a Generic for a HashSet?

Tags: c#

I want to do something like that, if its possible.

```
internal sealed class BufferPool<T, K> : K<Buffer<T>>
{
    public BufferPool() : base() {}
    //etc...
}
```

and then call this class like:

```
BufferPool<byte, HashSet> buffers;
buffers = new BufferPool<byte, HashSet>(bufferCapacity);
```

or

```
BufferPool<byte, List> buffers;
buffers = new BufferPool<byte, List>(bufferCapacity);
```

Comment: Have you tried it?  If so, what happened?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking here; could you describe the intention of what you're trying to construct?

Comment: Yes, I have tried but cant get it work.

Comment: the type Parameter 'K' cannot be used with type arguments.

Comment: deriving from the .NET collection classes is easier to implement but also easier to get into troubles. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2136235/932418

Answer (score 2):

You cannot inherit from a type parameter (see [How to inherit from a generic parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047830/how-to-inherit-from-a-generic-parameter)).  What you *can* do is constrain a type parameter to be of a useful type and a plain constructor, and instantiate an instance inside of your class:

```
internal sealed class BufferPool<T, K> : IEnumerable<T> where K : IEnumerable<T>, new()
{
    K _bufferImpl = new K();

    public BufferPool() : base() { }
    //etc...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That won't work because the compiler needs to know what type/interface your class is inheriting/implementing to determine if your class satisfies the contract requirements of that type. That includes overriding abstract members, implementing interface members, etc.

When you just have a type parameter there, the contract is unknown. This a situation that the compiler does not support.